# Dynamic dropdown in html in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, dynamic, dropdown

I am trying to build a simple Flask app where a user uploads a CSV file. Through a dropdown in the same form, the user should be able to select one column. Now, I need this dropdown to be populated based on the uploaded CSV headers. Looked across various solutions. Tried some that were marked as correct. Yet either I get the error "Nonetype object not iterable" or columns are not populated.

I cannot use json.

Based on the answer someone had posted in a different query, my codes are -

In app.py:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    col_names = request.args.get('col_names')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('file')
        if file and file.filename.endswith('.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
            col1 = request.form.get('col1')
            col2 = request.form.get('col2')
            col3 = request.form.get('col3')
            return render_template('upload.html', col_names=col_names,
                                   col1=col1, col2=col2, col3=col3)
        else:
            return 'Invalid file format'
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html', col_names=col_names)
```

In upload.html:

```
<form action="/upload?col_names={{ col_names }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">File:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"><br />
    <label for="col1">Column 1:</label>
    <select id="col1" name="col1">
        {% for col in col_names %}
        <option value="{{ col }}">{{ col }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="col2">Column 2:</label>
    <select id="col2" name="col2">
        {% for col in col_names %}
        <option value="{{ col }}">{{ col }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="col3">Column 3:</label>
    <select id="col3" name="col3">
        {% for col in col_names %}
        <option value="{{ col }}">{{ col }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br />
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

how do i populate these dropdowns?[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this, works for me. What is the value of `col_names`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to upload the file with javascript in the background as soon as it has been selected. Now the columns of the file can be extracted and offered for selection with a returned partial. If the form is finally sent, you will receive the file and the selected columns and can process them.

###### Flask (./app.py)

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    abort, 
    render_template,
    request 
)
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/csv-upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def csv_upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('file')
        cols = request.form.getlist('column')
        if file and file.filename.endswith('.csv') and len(cols) == 3:
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
            if len(df.columns) >= 3 and all(c in df.columns and cols.count(c) == 1 for c in cols): 
                print(df)
                print(cols)
    return render_template('csv_upload.html')

@app.post('/csv-columns')
def csv_columns():
    file = request.files.get('file')
    if file and file.filename.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        if len(df.columns) >= 3: 
            columns = df.columns
            return render_template('csv_columns.html', **locals())
    abort(400)
```

###### HTML (./templates/csv_upload.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Upload</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        fieldset[disabled] {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset name="file">
            <div>
                <label for="file">File:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="text/csv" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset name="columns" disabled>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" disabled>Upload</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            const fieldsetElem = document.querySelector('fieldset[name="columns"]');
            const fileElem = document.querySelector('input[name="file"]');
            const btnElem = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

            fileElem.addEventListener('change', async function(event) {
                btnElem.disabled = true;
                fieldsetElem.disabled = true;

                const data = await fetch('/csv-columns', {
                    method: 'POST', 
                    body: new FormData(this.form)
                }).then(resp => resp.ok && resp.text());

                if (data) {
                    fieldsetElem.innerHTML = data;

                    const selElems = Array.from(fieldsetElem.querySelectorAll('select[name="column"]'));
                    selElems.forEach(elem => {
                        elem.addEventListener('change', () => {
                            btnElem.disabled = !(selElems.every(e => e.value != '') 
                                && (new Set(Array.from(selElems, e => e.value))).size === selElems.length);
                        })
                    });

                    fieldsetElem.disabled = false;
                } else {
                    console.error('Something went wrong.')
                }

            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (./templates/csv_columns.html)

```html
{% for i in range(3) -%}
    <div>
        <label for="column-{{i}}">Column {{i+1}}</label>
        <select name="column" id="column-{{i}}">
            <option value selected>-- Select a column --</option>
            {% for col in columns -%}
            <option value="{{ col }}">{{ col }}</option>
            {% endfor -%}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endfor -%}
```